# Magento - pull one single customer review

Tags: php, magento

I've been trying to pull one single customer review onto the product page.

I've no code to show as honestly i'm not sure where to start and can't find any mention of it online.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a tutorial earlier on bringing all the review elements onto the product page, so you could follow this tutorial: http://www.e-commercewebdesign.co.uk/blog/magento-tutorials/product-reviews-on-product-view-page.php

All you'd have to do is rename the list block and bring it out in the same way. Then simply modify the loop which brings out the reviews in any way you see fit. E.g. limit to a certain number or only echo out review from a certain user.

**EDIT:**

To get the latest review is quite simple because the reviews are in date order anyway.

Go to **review > product > list.phtml**

Replace the code in that file with this:

```
<?php $_items = $this->getReviewsCollection()->getItems();?>
<div class="box-collateral box-reviews" id="customer-reviews">
<?php if (count($_items)):?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Customer Reviews') ?></h2>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('toolbar') ?>
    <dl>
    <?php $r_count = 0; ?>
    <?php foreach ($_items as $_review):?>
    <?php if ($r_count == 0) { ?>
        <dt>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getReviewUrl($_review->getId()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_review->getTitle()) ?></a> <?php echo $this->__('Review by <span>%s</span>', $this->htmlEscape($_review->getNickname())) ?>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <?php $_votes = $_review->getRatingVotes(); ?>
            <?php if (count($_votes)): ?>
            <table class="ratings-table">
                <col width="1" />
                <col />
                <tbody>
                    <?php foreach ($_votes as $_vote): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_vote->getRatingCode()) ?></th>
                        <td>
                            <div class="rating-box">
                                <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $_vote->getPercent() ?>%;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php echo nl2br($this->htmlEscape($_review->getDetail())) ?>
            <small class="date"><?php echo $this->__('(Posted on %s)',       $this->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt()), 'long') ?></small>
        </dd>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php $r_count++; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    </dl>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('toolbar') ?>
<?php endif;?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('review_form') ?>
</div>
```

I've simple put an interator into the loop **$r_count** and put a check inside the foreach which prevent it from progressing on the next loop iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the support again!, I do currently have the full review system on my product page, if you could give an example of how to pull the most recent comment based on that pages product. I would be very grateful