# limit number of product reveiws that display on product page magento

Tags: php, magento

So i have figured out how to display product reviews on a product page. Now I need to understand how to limit the number of review that display and add a "read more reviews" link to the product reviews default page.

Any ideas? Or Can anyone point me in the right direction? I have tried a number of different scripts with no luck.

UPDATE: I tried making the changes below but its still not working - any ideas on what i'm doing wrong?

Yeah thats what I thought, but its still not working, any ideas what i'm doing wrong??

```
<?php $_items = $this->getReviewsCollection()->setPageSize('5')->getItems();?>
<div class="box-collateral box-reviews" id="customer-reviews">
<?php if (count($_items)):?>
<div class="box-title">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Customer<br><span id="smallH2">Reviews</span>') ?></h2>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('toolbar') ?>
<dl class="box-content" id="product-reviews-list">
<?php foreach ($_items as $_review):?>
<dt>
<?php
$reviewURL = $this->getReviewUrl($_review->getId());
$reviewURL = str_replace("catalog","review",$reviewURL);
?>
<a href="<?php echo $reviewURL ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_review->getTitle())            ?></a>       <?php echo $this->__('Review by <span>%s</span>', $this->htmlEscape($_review->getNickname())) ?>
</dt> 
    <dd>
        <table class="data-table review-summary-table">
            <col />
            <col />
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($_review->getRatingVotes() as $_vote): ?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_vote->getRatingCode()) ?></th>
                    <td class="value">
                        <div class="rating-box">
                            <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $_vote->getPercent() ?>%;">    
</div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p><?php echo nl2br($this->htmlEscape($_review->getDetail())) ?></p>
        <p class="date"><?php echo $this->__('(Posted on %s)',    $this->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt()), 'long') ?></p>
    </dd>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('#product-reviews-list dd'), ['last']);</script>
<?php endif;?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('review_form') ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I ended up going with:

```
<?php
$i = 1;
foreach ($_items as $_review):
    if ($i < 6): ?>
```

Thanks for all that tried to help...

Comment: I would say this is a poor solution, as you are loading a large number of reviews to the page and then just limiting how many to display.  Very inefficient.  Look at the solution by @Cangzhou Wu

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this and found a more robust way.  In your theme's `review.xml` file find this line which creates the pager:

```
<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_review_list.toolbar" />
```

and replace it with the following (except with whichever number you like):

```
<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_review_list.toolbar">
    <action method="setLimit"><limit>6</limit></action>
</block>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
app\code\core\Mage\Review\Block\Product\View\List.php

 protected function _beforeToHtml()
{
    $this->getReviewsCollection()->setPageSize(5)
        ->load()
        ->addRateVotes();
    return parent::_beforeToHtml();
}
```

It's worked for me. Of course, you should rewrite the block

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using collections for fetching reviews. So you can make

```
$collection->setPageSize('number of reviews on page');
```

Comment: where would I put that? This is how the items are pulling in:

    <?php $_items = $this->getReviewsCollection()->getItems();?>

Is this the same line I would add your script to add the number of items?

Comment: yes, <?php $_items = $this->getReviewsCollection()->setPageSize('number of reviews on page')->getItems();?>

Comment: if you are adding reviews to the product page you should add block from review module. Insert blocks <block type="core/template" name="product_review_list.count" template="review/product/view/count.phtml" /> and <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_additional_data" template="review/product/view/list.phtml"/> to the <catalog_product_view> handle and replace review/product/view/list.phtml to your template

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042791/magento-pull-one-single-customer-review and it worked,now I just need to display "5" instead of 1??

Comment: Still really need an answer to this?? Any Ideas?